# how can i setup maradns / nsd server to answer a single IP address to any query

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, nsd

i tried the manual, but cant find how/if i can set it to answer single ip for all queries.

anyone tried any of these? which one works?

or any other smaller, secure bind alternatives?

tnx

nb. nsd: http://www.nlnetlabs.nl/projects/nsd/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i found it.

here how it goes with nsd:

add this to nsd.conf:

```
zone:
    name: "."
    zonefile: "root.zone"
    provide-xfr: 0.0.0.0/0 NOKEY
    provide-xfr: ::0/0 NOKEY
```

then create root.zone and fill it with:

```
$TTL 1H
@    IN     SOA  @ none. ( 11 1D 1H 1W 3H );
     IN     NS   @
     IN     A    1.2.3.4
```

then:

```
nsdc rebuild
nsdc reload
```

nb. you need to rebuild and reload everytime you change your zone file.

Answer (score 0):

Try my [evldns](http://code.google.com/p/evldns/) server framework.

There's an example program in that which always returns the same IP address for any `IN A` query.

Comment: i'm no programmer. any ready to use binary i can try? tnx

Comment: Sorry, no, it's a framework, not a ready-to-run DNS server.  However if you're running Linux it's pretty easy to build.